# Require a list of files in a more structured way

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a build problem that need to make a really fast fix and did this:(they are 10 more):

---

require get_parent_theme_file_path() . '/blocks/benefits/functions.php';

require get_parent_theme_file_path() . '/blocks/event-agenda/functions.php';

require get_parent_theme_file_path() . '/blocks/event-speakers/functions.php';

---

I like somehow to make a function that always includes these functions.php files

**Structure is /blocks/<name_of_block>/functions.php**

We always have block folder and each block cant work without its php file.

My idea is dynamically load each functions.php.
without knowing each parent folder name of the php file.
I always know it will be /blocks/<random_name>/functions.php

Comment: Are you asking about including the files based on a list of blocks names you will be providing, or about including the functions file for every folder that exists below `blocks/` dynamically?

Comment: I want with a loop dynamically to require each one
I just don`t know why. 
Like 
For (loop inside /blocks intill last folder )
{
require get_parent_theme_file_path() . '/blocks/*****/functions.php';
}
Or something like that

Comment: Well then read the contents of your blocks folder, and for each sub-folder you encounter, perform the require ...

Comment: Try out the asterisk in the path like **require get_parent_theme_file_path() . '/blocks/*/functions.php';**

Comment: And you could try to loop through the directories with this function **count(glob("/blocks/*/functions.php", GLOB_ONLYDIR)**